# Using Noobs on 8 GB SD card not using all space

Tags: sd-card, noobs

I have been using Noobs to install Raspbian on a Raspberry B+. I can see that it doesn't use the whole 8 GB of my card.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          3.0G  2.7G  139M  96% /
/dev/root       3.0G  2.7G  139M  96% /
devtmpfs        192M     0  192M   0% /dev
tmpfs            40M  250k   39M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            79M     0   79M   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p5   62M   11M   52M  17% /boot
```

And as you can see I still have space left:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo parted
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/mmcblk0
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: SD SA08G (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7747MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      4194kB  825MB   821MB   primary   fat16        lba
 2      826MB   3975MB  3149MB  extended
 5      830MB   893MB   62.9MB  logical   fat32        lba
 6      898MB   3975MB  3078MB  logical   ext4
 3      3975MB  4009MB  33.6MB  primary   ext4

(parted)
```

What can I do in order to expand the space and use all my sd card without reinstalling everything?

Thanks for the help.

John.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the raspi-config command and select the first option. You have to run it as the root user, so use:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

[image: rasp-config]